# lim sup inequality (with infinite sum)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Question: If $\limsup_{n\to\infty} a_n\leq l$, how do we show that $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n a_i/n\leq l$?

Is this question even valid? Consider the constant sequence $a_n\equiv 1$, then we may take $l=1$.

However $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n 1/n$ is the harmonic series which diverges.

Just to check if there is anything wrong with the question? (It is a PhD qualifying exam of a certain school.) I may have made a mistake on my part too.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's $\frac{1}{n}$, not $\frac{1}{i}$. Maybe it's better to write $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i$.

Comment: Oh i see... Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

For any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N$ such that $a_i < l + \epsilon$ for all $i > N$. Then take $\limsup$ of both sides of

$$\frac1{n}\sum_{i=1}^n a_i = \frac1{n}\sum_{i=1}^N a_i+ \frac1{n}\sum_{i=N+1}^n a_i< \frac1{n}\sum_{i=1}^N a_i+ \frac{n-N}{n}(l+\epsilon)$$